# Selecting the newest record of a hasMany relationship

Tags: cakephp

I have 2 basic models in my CakePHP application: User and Login. A user has a hasMany relation with Logins (i.e., a new login record is created everytime the user logs in).

Now, I want to make 2 relations from the User model to the Login model:
User hasMany Login
and
User hasOne lastLogin

This last relation should only include the last record of the Login model for the selected user.

I tried this as follows:

```
var $belongsTo = array
(
    'LastLogin' => array
    (
        'className' => 'Login',
        'order' => 'LastLogin.created DESC',
        'limit' =>  1

    )
);
```

However, this doesn't work. Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: *what* doesn't work? Unexpected data?

Comment: And perhaps it should be `'order' => 'Login.created DESC'` - as you are referring to the `Login` table?

Comment: I think you are over-doing model relationship. Why do you need a lastLogin when you can do a simple query on Login model to get one record?

Comment: @Ross: Correct, I get one record per login, whereas I need one record per user. Also, I should refer to LastLogin instead of Login, asthis is the table alias.

Comment: @Anh Pham: I could do that, but I'd rather do a single query to get all the info I need from that person. When showing a list of users, I am only interested in the latest login of that user.

Comment: then why not a lastLogin field in users table? Each time they log in, save the old entry to a new Login record, and save the new one there (if you still need the logins table).

Comment: @AnhPham: because I would have to store the same data twice. Semantically, I believe it's better to join in the newest login. Especially because I want to use the same approach in other models, where it would be a hassle to continuously update the parent record.

Comment: @Rick: Or consider just using the User hasMany Login relationship, and then pop off the last login record using PHP. That way you get all your data in one go and don't have to store anything twice. You could add something like if (!empty($user['Login'])) { $lastLogin = array_pop($user['Login']) }

Comment: @Rick: I've updated my answer with a slightly different approach that should solve your problem nicely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS**

With a `belongsTo` relationship, the foreign key should be in the **current** model.

This means that if you want to have a relationship where User belongsTo LastLogin, the `users` table should have a `last_login_id` field.

In your case you probably want to use a hasOne relationship instead, and you're going to have to use the `MAX()` SQL function in the `fields` key. Note that getting the last_login works completely independently of your User hasMany Login relationship. So if all you want is the last login you can remove the hasMany relationship and just leave the hasOne.

With the example code below you'll get this:

**Output of /users/index:**

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => user1
            [last_login] => 2011-05-01 14:00:00
        )
    [Login] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [created] => 2011-05-01 12:00:00
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [created] => 2011-05-01 13:00:00
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [created] => 2011-05-01 14:00:00
                )
        )
)
```

If you don't use the Model::afterFind() callback your results will look more like this (Login array snipped to save space):

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => user1
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [last_login] => 2011-05-01 14:00:00
        )
)
```

---

**Example code:**

**users table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**logins table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `logins` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**User model:**

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $hasMany = array('Login');
    var $hasOne = array(
        'LastLogin' => array(
            'className' => 'Login',
            'fields' => array('MAX(LastLogin.created) as last_login')
        )
    );

    // This takes the last_login field from the [0] keyed array and puts it into 
    // [User]. You could also put this into your AppModel and it would work for 
    // all find operations where you use an SQL function in the 'fields' key.
    function afterFind($results, $primary=false) {
        if (!empty($results)) {
            foreach ($results as $i => $result) {
                if (!empty($result[0])) { // If the [0] key exists in a result...
                    foreach ($result[0] as $key => $value) { // ...cycle through all its fields...
                        $results[$i][$this->alias][$key] = $value; // ...move them to the main result...
                    }
                    unset($results[$i][0]); // ...and finally remove the [0] array
                }
            }
        }
        return parent::afterFind($results, $primary=false); // Don't forget to call the parent::afterFind()
    }
}
```

**Users controller:**

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Users';

    function index() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        pr($this->User->find('all'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this, but when I have say, 4 logins for a user, I get 4 user records, one for each log in for that user. Adding a limit doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Strange, I've just done a quick test with this and it works for me. I'll update my answer with the code that I'm using so you can see. It's possible that the problem is coming from some other code in your app.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some working code. Hope it helps you figure out where you're having the problem.

Comment: Thanks again for helping out, and posting your code! In the view mode, it works like a charm. However, when I call the index function (either using the find('all'), or in Scaffold mode), I still get a record per login.

Comment: I see what you mean. I don't think there's any way of getting around the duplicate results using a hasOne relationship. In this case you might want to add LastLogin to your hasMany array and set its 'className' key to 'Login', its 'order' key to 'created desc' and its 'limit' key to '1'. You should be able to eliminate the duplicates this way.

Comment: how can afterFind work with pagination? It's not working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation but mine was

```
Product hasMany Price
```

I wanted a `Product hasOne CurrentPrice` with the `CurrentPrice` defined as the top most record found if sorted by `created` in desc order.

I solved mine this way. But I am going to use your User and LastLogin instead.

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $hasMany = array('Login');
    var $hasOne = array(
        'LastLogin' => array(
            'className' => 'Login',
            'order' => 'LastLogin.created DESC'
       )
   );
```

If you think about it, created and id has the same meaning. so you could also use id in descending order.

I am assuming that your table schema is similar to the [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7625966/80353) suggested by [mtnorthrop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485868/mtnorthrop).

i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
logins table:

CREATE TABLE `logins` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```